# Why is BULK INSERT rounding milliseconds for a DATETIME field?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to BULK INSERT data into DATETIME columns that include milliseconds.

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid(),
  StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
  EndTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
  Baz DECIMAL(7,3) NULL
);
```

My input csv file looks like this:

```
 ,2016-01-28 17:16:05.000,2016-01-28 17:17:04.999,5.693
 ,2016-01-28 17:17:05.000,2016-01-28 17:18:04.999,5.275
```

My BULK INSERT script looks like this:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Foo
FROM 'C:\foo.csv' 
WITH (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a');
```

But when I do a SELECT * on the inserted data, I get:

```
F80992B3-F9DB-E611-80C3-000D3AB157F3,2016-01-28 17:16:05.000,2016-01-28 17:17:05.000,5.693
F90992B3-F9DB-E611-80C3-000D3AB157F3,2016-01-28 17:17:05.000,2016-01-28 17:18:05.000,5.275
```

Why is BULK INSERT rounding up the EndTime milliseconds and how do I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because DATETIME has 3.33ms accuracy. This means that 4.999 got rounded to 5.000.

To avoid this issue use DATETIME2(3) instead.

There is really good explanation of this issue [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/)

Answer (score 4):

This is not `bulk insert`.  This is the nature of the `datetime` data type.  As (subtly) pointed out in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx):

> Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

So, the value is rounded to the appropriate increment.